# Spliting a string by a deliminator

Tags: c, clion, string.h

I'm writing a program in **Pure C** (A requirement for my end-of-year course project). It has a **.dat** file that stores csv values. I've found a function to read the file line by line and a function to split the line from the file by a deliminator, the string split function worked perfectly fine until a change in IDEs. I have a student license with JetBrains and recently bought a 64bit laptop so I upgraded to CLion. Then started having problem with that specific bit of code, it hangs my program when ever it reaches that line of code, more specifically when reading the final separation in the string.

**functions.c::str_split**

```
char** str_split(char* a_str, const char a_delim)
{
    char** result    = 0;
    size_t count     = 0;
    char* tmp        = a_str;
    char* last_comma = 0;
    char delim[2];
    delim[0] = a_delim;
    delim[1] = 0;

    /* Count how many elements will be extracted. */
    while (*tmp)
    {
        if (a_delim == *tmp)
        {
            count++;
            last_comma = tmp;
        }
        tmp++;
    }

    /* Add space for trailing token. */
    count += last_comma < (a_str + strlen(a_str) - 1);

    /* Add space for terminating null string so caller
       knows where the list of returned strings ends. */
    count++;

    result = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);

    if (result)
    {
        size_t idx  = 0;
        char* token = strtok(a_str, delim);

        while (token)
        {
            assert(idx < count);
            *(result + idx++)= strdup(token);
            token = strtok(0, delim);
        }
        assert(idx == count - 1);
        *(result + idx) = 0;
    }

    return result;
}
```

And it is called like this in **main.c::main**

```
...
while ((read =(size_t)getline(&file_line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
       char **tokens;
       tokens = str_split(file_line, ',');
...
```

The program hangs on this line... Not throwing an error but when stopped with the GDB Debugger shows and the IDE also tries to rectify this error by suggesting a lib include that could help, but this also leads to no avail....
[image: Output from the debugger..]

Comment: **pure c** is this an editor..., IDE ?

Comment: `strdup` is not a standard library function, but some implementations put `strdup` in `<string.h>`. CLion evidently has `strdup` in `<mem.h>`, so try including that file.

Comment: You should check malloc for errors

Comment: Is it possible that the text line is too long for file_line to hold all the characters?

Comment: @user3386109 It's not a mem.h function, it's certain to be a string.h function.

Comment: @Michi The problem has already been rectified. Please see answer below.

Comment: @PanRuochen The problem has already been rectified. Please see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was rectified, the CMakeList.txt was edited by some arbitrary means and the C compilation standards were changed. It was changed to c11, the standard c11 does not implement the the strdup() the same way standard c99 uses and it was written using the c99 standard not c11.

Comment: actually, the real problem is:  to get the prototype for `strdup()`, the code must be compiled with one or more of the following defined: ` _SVID_SOURCE || _BSD_SOURCE || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500 ||
           _XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED
           || /* Since glibc 2.12: */ _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L`   Suggest placing this statement at the start of the source file: `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE = 200809L`   Note: This definition is often needed.  Suggest editing the setup for the IDE to place this in the `-D` parameters